# I would expect the output to be like [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],[2,4,6,8,10,12...18,20],[3,6,9...27,30].....[9,18,27..90]]

Tags: python, list, loops, nested-loops, nested-lists

I'm using python.I need to get output as I mention in bottom. This is the way I try.

```
 L = [i for i in range(1,11)]
    print(L)
    p = []
    p.extend(L for _ in range(10))
    #print(p)
    for _ in range(10):
        for i in range(10):
            p[_][i] = (_+1)*p[_][i]
    print(p)
and this is the output I got.
```

> Output:[[3628800, 7257600, 10886400, 14515200, 18144000, 21772800
>   25401600, 29030400, 32659200, 36288000], [3628800, 7257600, 10886400,
>   14515200, 18144000, 21772800, 25401600, 29030400, 32659200, 36288000],
>   [3628800, 7257600, 10886400, 14515200, 18144000, 21772800, 25401600,
>   29030400, 32659200, 36288000], [3628800, 7257600, 10886400, 14515200,
>   18144000, 21772800, 25401600, 29030400, 32659200, 36288000], [3628800,
>   7257600, 10886400, 14515200, 18144000, 21772800, 25401600, 29030400,
>   32659200, 36288000], [3628800, 7257600, 10886400, 14515200, 18144000,
>   21772800, 25401600, 29030400, 32659200, 36288000], [3628800, 7257600,
>   10886400, 14515200, 18144000, 21772800, 25401600, 29030400, 32659200,
>   36288000], [3628800, 7257600, 10886400, 14515200, 18144000, 21772800,
>   25401600, 29030400, 32659200, 36288000], [3628800, 7257600, 10886400,
>   14515200, 18144000, 21772800, 25401600, 29030400, 32659200, 36288000],
>   [3628800, 7257600, 10886400, 14515200, 18144000, 21772800, 25401600,
>   29030400, 32659200, 36288000]]

I would expect the output to be like

```
[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],[2,4,6,8,10,12...18,20],[3,6,9...27,30].....[9,18,27..90]]
```

Comment: The question is : how to get the expected output or why do you get that strange output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems: 
Do not use _ as a variable name it's for variables you won't reuse.

You are getting this problem because of this line:

```
p.extend(L for _ in range(10))
```

p is a list of references to L. So when you do:

```
p[_][i] = (_+1)*p[_][i]
```

you modify L, and thus all the lists in p.

Your code fixed:

```
p = []
p.extend(list(range(1,11)) for _ in range(10))

for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        p[i][j] = (i+1)*p[i][j]
print(p)
```

However, there is a simpler way to do it:

```
p  = [ list(range(i, i*11, i )) for i in range(1,10)]
```

Comment: Some further info on this can be found here: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html

Comment: Hi, you said L is modified after the line p[_][i] = (_+1)*p[_][i] is executed but when I print L, in the end, It still retains its initial value.

Comment: so my question is: If L is changing then why don't I see the change when I print it again in the end?

Comment: If I copy/paste your code and print(L) in the end L is worth : [3628800, 7257600, 10886400, 14515200, 18144000, 21772800, 25401600, 29030400, 32659200, 36288000], it is modified

Comment: yeah, yes you were right, It indeed did change. But do you know why the starting value of the list ended up to be 3628800??

Comment: Yes,  your multiplying the 9 fist integers together which is 9! wich is 3628800. More info [link](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Factorial)

Comment: yeah, I see it now! for each iteration, the value of L gets updated by the multiplying factor and that value is used to extend p and it goes on till the multiplying factor is 9 and hence 9! is the accumulated multiple. Man! gotta be careful with lists

Answer (score 0):

```
L = [i for i in range(1,11)]
print(L)
d = []
for i in range(1, 11):
    d.append([i * j for j in L])

print(d)
```

output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20], [3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30], [4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36, 40], [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50], [6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 42, 48, 54, 60], [7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 49, 56, 63, 70], [8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48, 56, 64, 72, 80], [9, 18, 27, 36, 45, 54, 63, 72, 81, 90], [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]]
```

Comment: That's great, But I just want some help in figuring out why my approach leads to a different output as opposed to what I expect it to be.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
new_data = [list(filter(lambda x:not x%i, range(i, (10*i)+1))) for i in range(1,10)]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20], [3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30], [4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36, 40], [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50], [6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 42, 48, 54, 60], [7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 49, 56, 63, 70], [8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48, 56, 64, 72, 80], [9, 18, 27, 36, 45, 54, 63, 72, 81, 90]]
```